# Android -Dynamic TextView over previous TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, dinamico

I am making an example of dynamic textview, that are created by pressing a button. the format in which they are created is similar to:

```
1- Textview (fist created)
2- TextView
3- TextView (last created)
```

I wonder if we can create them in an ascending order, one above the previous TextView.
something like this:

```
3- TextView (last created)
2- TextView
1- TextView (first created)
```

this is my example code:

```
 private OnClickListener onClick() {
     return new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("TextView"));
             count = count +1;
         }
     };
 }

 private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
     final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
     textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
     textView.setText(count+ "- " + text);
     textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
     return textView;
 }}
```

Comment: Why not just change content ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the index where `TextView` has to be added in `ViewGroup`...

```
ViewGroup.addView(TextView, 0);
```

each time you are creating a TextView and adding to `mLayout`, add with the `index` 0 which will add on top of previous `TextView`

```
mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("TextView"),0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `LinearLayout` and add one below the other, using `layout.addView(TextView)`. I've a psedo code below which explains how it is done.

```
for(Option option : options){
     view = View.inflate(mContext,R.layout.textView,null);
     ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_key)).setText(" SOME TEXT : ");
     ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_value)).setText("SOME VALUE ");
     mLlCtr.addView(view);
}
```